# How correct config .htaccess + fastcgi?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

There is a bunch of Fastcgi + Apache on Win 2003.

`http://www.xxx.ru` works

and `http://www.xxx.ru/api/get_privacy_policy` for some reason does not work. Tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
Options -Multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://www.xxx.ru/api/get_privacy_policy`? Do you get a blank page or an error, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Scamtex http://176.114.9.136/api/get_privacy_policy

Comment: It shows an error of **ISS**, so you have Apache AND ISS set up? Try disabling ISS in that case